# RadioButtons are not mutually exclusive, despite same GroupName (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a ListView, that represents a list of products which only one of them should be chosen. in the ItemTemplate, I gave all the RadioButton the same GroupName property in order for them to be mutually exclusive. However, it does not work so right now all of the products can be chosen at once. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <li class="product" id='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>'>
    <asp:RadioButton GroupName="products" ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
  </li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This feature of `RadioButton` will not work in `ListView`,`GridView` and may be few other listing controls. You need to use `JQuery` or pure `JavaScript` for this.

Comment: You should probably use the RadioButtonList control in this case.

Comment: It looks like a [bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316495) in the RadioButton control as far back as ASP.Net 1.1. `RadioButtonList` appears to be the accepted solution